# Use edge js on openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, edge.js

I'm trying to run C# on my OpenShift cartridge with [Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge). It runs really good on my Windows PC and I would like to have it running on the cloud.
I'm guessing it runs on a Linux environment but I'm not shure.
At first I tried to make it work with my MSSQL DB and than move on to the C# assembly.
Nevertheless I'm doing the same steps as how I've got it to work on my Windows machine but I'm getting thesame errors over and over again.
I've added edge and edge-sql to my npm and my package.json.
Then I've make a simple count to my MSSQL DB.
When I'm running it locally it works great. Than I push it to OpenShift and I tail the application, because the front-end gives me an Error 503, and the next thing I know the following error makes me keepings my hands in my hair.

```
Error: The edge native module is not available at /var/lib/openshift/54d26260fcf
933d05e00021a/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/edge/build/Release/edge.node. Y
ou can use EDGE_NATIVE environment variable to provide alternate location of edg
e.node. If you need to build edge.node, follow build instructions for your platf
orm at https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/54d26260fcf933d05e00021a/app-root/
runtime/repo/node_modules/edge/lib/edge.js:33:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/54d26260fcf933d05e00021a/app-root/
runtime/repo/server.js:5:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
/var/lib/openshift/54d26260fcf933d05e00021a/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/e
dge/lib/edge.js:33
throw new Error('The edge native module is not available at ' + builtEdge
```

Could somebody help me to fix this error or maybe explain to me why it could / wont work?

Answer (score 0):

If edge requires a native windows environment to run C#, then it will not work on OpenShift, which runs on Red Hat Linux.